# What is the fastest way to add indices and an ID primary key column to a large table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have about 300 tables in my Postgres (`PostgreSQL 9.6.5-1`) database. The tables are large, each with about 6 million records. To insert the records, I created the tables without any indexes as I have found it is substantially faster to insert without any. I did not add an ID column (primary key, auto increment, unique), either.

I now need to add indices to each table, as well as a new ID column.
To do this, I use the following commands:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS some_table_1_index ON some_table_1 (latitude, longitude, measurement_time, level, speed, altitude);
ALTER TABLE some_table_1 ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

I have found that it takes between 30 and 90 seconds per command...meaning that it would take 7h30 to do all my tables (assuming a worst-case scenario of 90s per command).

Is there a faster way to alter all my tables?

I am using `Python` and `psycopg2`, if that makes any difference.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE some_table_1 ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;`Adding a column will force a complete rewrite of the table.(it will need to get bigger) Better is to add the serial when creating the table, (before importing),and making it a PK afterwards.This will only create the index in the final step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your command doesn't create four indices. It creates two indices in which the first is a composite index (which may not be exactly what you want because column order matters whether or not the planner will choose to use the index).

Second, are you executing the `CREATE` commands serially? Could you run all 300 create commands in parallel?

Psuedo code since I don't know Python well:

```
tableList = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3', ...]
createSql = 'CREATE INDEX...[0]...'
[executeInThread(table) for table in tableList]
```

Comment: Hmm, I am running them all in serial, one after the other. How could I run them in parallel?

Comment: You could do this a number of ways. One approach is to use threads in Python (although I'm not familiar with Python's threading model), to loop through your list of tables and apply the CREATE statements to each in a separate thread. A second approach is to create a command line script that does the same thing but forks a command against executes against the database for each table.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was hoping there was some DB magic that I could try.